# fill an array with dicts

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, vuejs3

In my survey component, I want to fill an array with many dicts each time I click on resp and store it on ref variable,
but the dicts are overwritten when I push new one in array.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const {QuizData,id} = defineProps({
    QuizData :Object,
    id:Number
})


var QuizToSub = ref([]);


const scrollToNext = (response) => {
    const nextSection = document.getElementById(`${id + 2}`);
    const quizDict = { qst: QuizData.question, rep: response };
    QuizToSub.value.push(quizDict)
    
    console.log(QuizToSub)
    if (nextSection) {
        nextSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Dicts are called objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help debug this, I would make sure this component is not being destroyed for each `nextSection`. If it is being destroyed, then the `ref([])` will get reset. That seems to be the issue.

To make sure, you can add a [created function](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-hooks) and reload the page

```
created () {
  console.log("I am mounted")
}
```

you should only see the log the first time you load the page. If you see it again when you go to the next section the component is being recreated and `QuizToSub` is being reset to `[]`.

One way to handle this, is to declare `QuizToSub` in the parent component and pass it as a prop into your Survey component. Another way is to not not destroy your component every time you go to the next section.

Comment: D you're right, ijust move the function from componet to view and pass all argument with emit , and the array is filled perfectly, thanks